# Compare Data Property values using Protege and Fact++

Tags: owl, protege, fact++

Using protege I'm trying to compare string values with data properties. E.g.:

I have a country class, and in that class I have an individual with a hasCountryName data property set to "England". I'm using a defined class, and what I want to do is say something like:

Country and (hasCountryName value "England")

Using the Hermit reasoner, it correctly infers that my individual is a member of that class, but using Fact++ it does not. I'd like to use the Fact++ reasoner, is there any way I can modify this so Fact++ recognises it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FaCT++ and HermiT are supposed to support the same inferences, so if this works with one but not the other I suspect a bug.
To confirm this, you can try the same example but using something like

```
Country and (hasCountry value England)
```

where `hasCountry` is an object property.
This does not make sense in terms of your original ontology, but the same inference should be kicked off without using data properties and literals. If FaCT++ recognizes this, then there is a bug in how it works with literals and datatype properties.